# google sheet conditional formatting for grading

Tags: google-sheets

On my google sheet for its form, I have the answers in Row 2.

There are 109 columns in which I need to check if the descending rows of each column match the contents of Row 2 of that column. On top of that, I have to have conditional formatting for the cells that DO NOT match the contents of Row 2 in their respective column.

Is there a way that I don't have to add a formula to each any every column?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with conditional formatting - for the "apply to range" section (pretending your data starts in column A and ends in D, although in reality you will put whatever the last column is) enter in

```
A2:D
```

then for the rule, choose custom formula and enter in this exact formula:

```
=if(eq(indirect(address(row(),COLUMN(),4)),indirect(ADDRESS(2,column(),2)))=TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)
```

This will dynamically highlight all of the answers that do not match the value in row 2